# How to convert HEX string to HTML Entities

Tags: c++

How to convert a HEX string to HTML entities? for reference (https://v2.cryptii.com/hexadecimal/htmlentities)

For example, convert "627 644 64a 648 645" to "&#1575;&#1604;&#1610;&#1608;&#1605;"

I am new in c++ and challenging with Arabic characters. Now I have a HEX string for that Arabic characters and I need to convert it into HTML entities so I can store in DB and then display in the browser.

```
string HEX_string="627 644 64a 648 645";
string html_entities=getHtmlEntities(HEX_string);

cout << "html_entities:" << html_entities << "\n";
```

I expect the output of code to be,

```
html_entities:&#1575;&#1604;&#1610;&#1608;&#1605;
```

What will be the implementation of this(getHtmlEntities) function?

Comment: What have you tried already? Are these HTML values simply the decimal representation of the hexadecimal values in the string?... Or is there special details to consider to get the result you expect?

Comment: Divide it into separate tasks and it will become much simpler: splitting the string, parsing numbers, convert to HTML representation, concatenate HTML representations.

Comment: For the number conversion use `std::stoi`.

Comment: For spliting the string use `std::istringstream` (among other possibilities)

Comment: In fact with `std::istringstream` you could use `std::hex` and do the splitting and converting in one operation.

Comment: Please make an attempt. Try something. We don't just do it for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int getDecimal(string HexNumber)
{
    int i, r, len, hex = 0;
    len = HexNumber.length();
    for (i = 0; HexNumber[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        len--;
        if(HexNumber[i] >= '0' && HexNumber[i] <= '9')
            r = HexNumber[i] - 48;
        else if(HexNumber[i] >= 'a' && HexNumber[i] <= 'f')
            r = HexNumber[i] - 87;
        else if(HexNumber[i] >= 'A' && HexNumber[i] <= 'F')
            r = HexNumber[i] - 55;
        hex += r * pow(16,len);
    }
    return hex;
}

string getHtmlEntities(string HEX_string)
{

    istringstream iss(HEX_string);
    string HTML_entities="";
    string s;
    while (getline(iss,s,' '))
    {
        int DecimalNumber=getDecimal(s.c_str());
        HTML_entities+="&#";
        HTML_entities+=to_str(DecimalNumber);
        HTML_entities+=";";
    }
    return HTML_entities;
}

int main() 
{

    string HEX_string="627 644 64a 648 645";
    string HTML_entities=getHtmlEntities(HEX_string);

    cout << "HTML_entities:" << HTML_entities;
    return 0;
}
```